# Dominated Convergence Theorem properties

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

The original definition for Dominated Convergence Theorem is that $X_n\xrightarrow { a.s.}X$ and $|X_n|\le Y \ \ \ \ \forall n\implies E(X_n)\to E(X)$.

However if we replace *almost sure* conevergence with convergence *in probability*, then also the theorem holds.

So I want to know what is the most general version of DCT? In particular, in what other types of convergences does the theorem work? What are the other conditions that we can relax and still have DCT holding?

Comment: Doesn't the "original definition" for the DCT guarantee a stronger statement, namely $\mathbb{E}[\lvert X-X_n\rvert] \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$?

Comment: Also, have a look at [these lecture notes](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~dhunter/asymp/lectures/p76to84.pdf), Exercise 3.12. To have convergence of the expectations, once you have convergence in distribution you can relax the domination hypothesis to uniform integrability.

Comment: I deleted my answer, since as @ClementC. mentioned, it failed to relax the assumptions. Actually, I will take a look at the lecture notes as well, since I have never seen the DCT formulated with the weaker hypotheses.

Comment: The thing is, I don't believe it's the DCT in all its "full glory" that can be relaxed that way. The conclusion you want is a corollary of (and is strictly weaker than) the full DCT, which I guess is why weaker assumptions are enough.

Comment: You have $L^1$ convergence if and only if you have uniform integrability and convergence in probability. Since this is an equivalency, it doesn't get more general than that. But of course you may want to find different characterizations of convergence in probability and uniform integrability.

Comment: Thanks.. @ClementC. What you said in your first comment is true. However can you please explain to me why $\Bbb{E}[|X_n-X|]\xrightarrow [n\to\infty] {} 0$ is a stronger statement than $\Bbb{E}[X_n]\xrightarrow [n\to\infty] {} \Bbb{E} [X] ?$

Comment: @Calculon Can you please elaborate , perhaps with an example?

Comment: Well, one implies the other, so one has that the first is stronger. Now, strictly stronger is just a general statement, which may or may not apply in this particular setting given the additional assumptions (I can find two r.v.s which have $\mathbb{E}[\lvert X-Y\rvert] > 0$ but $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[Y]$, e.g. choosing a good $X$ and setting $X=-Y$).

Comment: DCT or uniform integrability + convergence in probability give indeed a stronger conclusion, i.e. $\mathbb{E}[|X_n-X|]\to 0$. However, if one assumes DCT or uniform integrability + convergence *in law* only, then still $\mathbb{E}[X_n]\to \mathbb E[X]$, but, of course the convergence $\mathbb{E}[|X_n-X|]\to 0$ cannot be true in general.

Comment: @Qwerty I am not sure what kind of example you are looking for. The proof of that statement you can find for instance in the book of Williams (Probability with Martingales).

Comment: Nevermind mind what previous (deleted) comment, I realize now what I was misreading in Calculon's comment.

Comment: @ClementC. The statement I gave is different than the one you gave a link to. I have convergence in probability in lieu of convergence in distribution and $L^1$ convergence in lieu of convergence of expectations. The question seems to be about convergence of expectations but as you said the "classical" DCT is about $L^1$ convergence, which is stronger. So there is some confusion here I think.

Comment: @Calculon Yes, I realized that after. (misread "in probability" for "in distribution"). Now, does that mean that the dominated assumption in the "full" DCT can be relaxed/modified to uniform integrability?

Comment: @ClementC. Yes.

Comment: @zhoraster The statement you gave is exactly the type of a answer I am looking for. Can you refer me a proof of the your statement?

Comment: OK, after your comment it looks  to me that each of the two assumptions in the DCT is stronger than its counterpart (but easier to state). So we could have (convergence a.s.+uniform integrability), (convergence in probability+domination), or the weakest (convergence in probability+uniform integrability) as possible assumptions for the (full) DCT? @Calculon

Comment: @ClementC. Yes but the "full" DCT applies for any measure. What I said is valid in the context of probability spaces (as far as I know).

Comment: But @zhoraster said something about (convergence in law+uniform integrability)?

Comment: @Calculon Thanks for the clarifications!

Comment: @Qwerty If you are talking about convergence of expectations, then there is another equivalency. Namely, the expectations converge if and only if there is convergence in distribution and asymptotic uniform integrability.

Comment: @ClementC. You are welcome.